# When using Translation Manager can all (appropriate) schema fields be set to be translated by default?

Tags: translation-manager

The [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-5987B065-A251-4CC5-A08A-7FE50F5D4648&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-5987B065-A251-4CC5-A08A-7FE50F5D4648.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5987B065-A251-4CC5-A08A-7FE50F5D4648) seems to indicate not:

> ... You
>   need to select the Translatable check box in Schemas if you want to
>   allow these fields to be sent for translation...

However I was wondering if it there was some schema level setting to have all fields sent for translation by default. The use case is for a resource schema(s) containing translatable labels. From time to time new fields will be added for new resources, and its one more thing to remember to ensure they have the Translatable box checked.

Answer (score 3):

There is no out of the box setting for this.

You can write a Tridion core event handler to make fields translatable on Schema save - the translatable setting for a field is stored in the XSD of the Schema.